# How to Concatinate elements of a list in an order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i combine elements of a list in order to create a list in which the order remains the same.
For example  i have a list `a=[1,2,3]` and I want a list `b=[12,13,23]` I've been thinking about this but wasn't able to come up with an appropriate solution for list which has more than 3 elements(11 maybe).For now I have hardcoded this for a list with 3 elements but I'd like to know a smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Also could try `itertools.combinations`:

```
import itertools

a = [1, 2, 3]
print([int("".join(i)) for i in itertools.combinations("".join(map(str, a)), 2)])
```

Result:

```
[12, 13, 23]
```

Answer (score 1):

As a brute force solution you can run 2 loops

```
In [155]: a
Out[155]: [1, 2, 3]

In [156]: temp = []

In [160]: for i in range(len(a)):
     ...:     for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
     ...:         temp.append(int(f"{a[i]}{a[j]}"))
     ...:
     ...:

In [161]: temp
Out[161]: [12, 13, 23]
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering ! But i was wondering if  there was some other way to do this as this only works when we take 2 elements at a time , like for example if we want  [123,231,321].....
Thanks A LOT!!!!

Comment: what i am trying to say is that the number of elements is also variable , I am so sorry i forgot to mention that , i will edit it right away , but for the meantime the number of elements can be entered by the user. Thanks  a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools like this:

```
import itertools
a = [1,2,3,4]

it = itertools.combinations(a, 2)
temp = []
for comb in it:
  temp.append(f"{comb[0]}{comb[1]}")

temp
```